# Bootstrap4 cards not lining up next to each other. Stacking instead

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="Castle.jpg" alt="Card image fluid">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h3 class="card-title">Magic Kingdom</h3>
                <p>Walt Disney World's most popular park! Full of Attractions, characters, dining, and fireworks!</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More!</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

here is my code for one card. I pasted this code four time, as i want 4 different cards, but the cards are stacking on top of one another, instead of side by side. how do I fix? Thanks for any help, this is really bothering me.

Comment: Add your working code here

Comment: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

All four cards should be within one div of the `class="row"`. The cards stacked up on top of each other because you put them in different row tags.

```
<div class="row">
  <!--   Card 1 -->
  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="Castle.jpg" alt="Card image fluid">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h3 class="card-title">Magic Kingdom</h3>
        <p>Walt Disney World's most popular park! Full of Attractions, characters, dining, and fireworks!</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More!</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--   Card 2 -->
  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="Castle.jpg" alt="Card image fluid">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h3 class="card-title">Magic Kingdom</h3>
        <p>Walt Disney World's most popular park! Full of Attractions, characters, dining, and fireworks!</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More!</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--   Card 3 -->
  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="Castle.jpg" alt="Card image fluid">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h3 class="card-title">Magic Kingdom</h3>
        <p>Walt Disney World's most popular park! Full of Attractions, characters, dining, and fireworks!</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More!</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--   Card 4 -->
  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="Castle.jpg" alt="Card image fluid">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h3 class="card-title">Magic Kingdom</h3>
        <p>Walt Disney World's most popular park! Full of Attractions, characters, dining, and fireworks!</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More!</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your breakpoint will be. If you wrap each card on a `col-sm-6` than `col-md-6` div, it will probably wrap two of them on the same line.
And remember, `container` and `row` classes are 100% width, so cards must be inside of them (inside `row` specifically).